# Use socketIO.emit in external controller client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have the following problem. I want to separate all socket.emit functions from the client into a separate controller class so I can call the Controller functions and receive the response:

app/components/client.js

```
let response = NodeController.root(path);
console.log('response', response);
if(response){
    var projectInfoId = JSON.parse(response);
}
```

app/controller/node-controller.js

```
class NodeController {
    static root(data){
        let tmp;
        socket.emit('/', data, function (response) {
            tmp = response;
        });
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

The projectInfoId in client.js will be undefined because the response is undefined. If i call socket.emit() directly in the client with the callback function, I will receive the data und my projectInfoId will contain something.

Is it possblie to sepearte the socket functions from the client.js code or do I have to call it directly in the client.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case of trying to use return on an asynchronous function. The correct way to do this is adding a callback on your root function like this:

```
class NodeController {
    static root(data, callback){
        let tmp;
        socket.emit('/', data, function (response) {
            tmp = response;
            callback(tmp);
        });
    }
}
```

and then using it like this:

```
    let response = NodeController.root(path, function(response){
  console.log('response', response);
    if(response){
        var projectInfoId = JSON.parse(response);
    }
});
```

There are some other ways to handle async functions. One of them is async.js npm module ( yes it can work on the client ), using function generators or even using promises.

Comment: Just a simple callback function. Thank you!